# How to create a loop that goes thought find and let's user select files?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I got a loop so far that prints all the paths from find command:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line ; do
    echo "Processing... $line"
done < <(find /home/$USER -type d \( -name ".*" \) -prune -o -type f -size +10M -user $USER -writable -printf '%s %p\0'  |
        sort -z -n -k1 |
        awk -v RS="\0" '
        {
            file = $0; gsub(/^[^ ]* /, "", file)
            print file
        }')
```

I need to find a way this script ***displays these files to user and let him select and unselect them*** and after a finished selection returns these paths to script that will remove those files or pack them.

Comment: If there's user interaction, you might as well split up your program into collection, selection, action.

Comment: @Roadowl Thanks for the advice! But I don't really have a idea how to do that in one script, like to not output data from that loop to txt file or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [fzf tool](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf). It accepts stdin and shows the list of lines to the user and lets them select what they want. When the user submits, fzf will use stdout to print the selection. Example:

```bash
selection=$(ls | fzf)
echo "user selected: $selection"
```

Use `fzf -m` to let user select multiple lines.

Alternatively, use [vipe tool](https://packages.debian.org/buster/moreutils), or [gum](https://github.com/charmbracelet/gum), or [fzy](https://github.com/jhawthorn/fzy).

Comment: tested it! It's really cool feature but I'm wondering is there a built in GNU utility like that?

Comment: Not that [I know of](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/index.html). If you can't afford adding a dependency, either reimplement some prompt-based selection or put the whole list in a temp file and spawn `$EDITOR` on the temp file to let user remove lines they don't desire.